# How and where to add certificates for citrix receiver

Tags: 14.04, citrix

I have an ubuntu box running 14.04 LTS and provided to me by my employer. Now in the corporate world everything is under a firewall. I have managed to install Citrix receiver on my ubuntu machine as described in the official guide. My employer has provided me 3 more certificates with a .cer extension. However I have no clue how and where to add these. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Test it, please. (It is add all certificate from Mozilla, to Citrix).

> sudo ln -s /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/*   /opt/Citrix/ICAClient/keystore/cacerts

It's working.